# Minecraft Spawning Problem?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

Whenever I join a server I get stuck inside a person, and whenever I try to move out of that person I get glitched back inside a person. What is going on? My Minecraft version is 1.5.2 and I am trying to join a 1.5.2 server.

Comment: ... 1.5.2 is super old. Use 1.8 instead

Answer (score 2):

There could be multiple reasons you are teleported back into your spawn point:
- You have a bad connection
- The server is lagging
- The server is using a verification plugin (You need to login to the server)

Answer (score 0):

More than likely it requires you to login to the server. In the chat, it should tell you how to do that. Also, 1.5.2 is ancient. Update to 1.8.7